# how to use Zend Session Destroy in zf1.12.0?

Tags: zend-framework, session

I want to implement **destroy** session for logout functionality.How to use zend session destroy?

Answer (score 1):

```
$session = new Zend_session_Namespace('Your_namespace');
$session->unsetAll();
```

Comment: Should I write it in controller?